# CSS precedence query

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I've got a fairly basic website setup using JQuery-UI theme css which is taken from a content server. This CSS is cannot be changed. What I am wanting to do is override some of the css from JQuery themes, for example change from:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

to

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

What is the best way to override the CSS? Do I hack with !important or is there an alternative (other than defining the new rule directly into the webpage).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options without using !important.

**You can add specificity:**

```
body .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

**Define the overriding rule after the initial rule.**

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

... (separate file loaded later, or same file, just further down:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a CSS declaration "more specific" to override it.

You specify something up the HTML tree to do this:

```
div ui-tabs
```

or

```
div.wrappingClass .ui-tabs
```

or the brute-force method:

```
body .ui-tabs
```

Here is a handy tool for checking this:

http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php